# 'Attribute already defined' Error in App build in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

While trying to build App in Xamarin, I get the following error.

Why is the following error occurring and how can it be resolved?

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Source  Suppression State
>   Error     Attribute "expanded" has already been
>   defined   MyApp.Droid C:\Users\userName\Desktop\Xamarin_Apps\MyApp\MyApp\MyApp.Droid\obj\Release\resourcecache\0849AF72F7656C03143D998D49444C1F\res\values\values.xml 14  Build
>   Error     Attribute "layout_scrollFlags" has already been
>   defined   MyApp.Droid C:\Users\userName\Desktop\Xamarin_Apps\MyApp\MyApp\MyApp.Droid\obj\Release\resourcecache\0849AF72F7656C03143D998D49444C1F\res\values\values.xml 15  Build
>   Error     Attribute "layout_scrollInterpolator" has already been
>   defined   MyApp.Droid C:\Users\userName\Desktop\Xamarin_Apps\MyApp\MyApp\MyApp.Droid\obj\Release\resourcecache\0849AF72F7656C03143D998D49444C1F\res\values\values.xml 15  Build
>   Error     Attribute "behavior_peekHeight" has already been
>   defined   MyApp.Droid C:\Users\userName\Desktop\Xamarin_Apps\MyApp\MyApp\MyApp.Droid\obj\Release\resourcecache\0849AF72F7656C03143D998D49444C1F\res\values\values.xml 16  Build
>   Error     Attribute "behavior_hideable" has already been
>   defined   MyApp.Droid C:\Users\userName\Desktop\Xamarin_Apps\MyApp\MyApp\MyApp.Droid\obj\Release\resourcecache\0849AF72F7656C03143D998D49444C1F\res\values\values.xml 16  Build
>   Error     Attribute "layout_collapseMode" has already been
>   defined   MyApp.Droid C:\Users\userName\Desktop\Xamarin_Apps\MyApp\MyApp\MyApp.Droid\obj\Release\resourcecache\0849AF72F7656C03143D998D49444C1F\res\values\values.xml 17  Build

[image]

Comment: Have you tried a clean and rebuild?

Comment: yes, I have tried it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems is a mismatch on the Google Android Support libraries , you need to make sure that you have installed the correct version of the support libraries, the ones that Forms uses. You could have other library that request a different version and it can also cause this issues.

Make sure you remove all packages and add the latest stable version of forms. Clean, and rebuild.